# Cannot find method getRange(number,number)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't set a variable to return the number to the last row under the K column in google sheets. The code fails on the last line `.setValues(exampleText)` where I have already defined `exampleText` as a variable.

I have used different methods of setting variables including setting a variable for a column.

I get the following error:

> "Cannot find method getRange(number,number)."

The top three rows are an example I tried before.

```
Column = 'K' 
range = ss.getRange(LastRow, Column)
range.setValue(exampleText)

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var column = 11

var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

ss.getRange(lastRow, column)
.setValues(exampleText)
```

Comment: `getRange(row,column)` type syntax only accepts numbers NOT strings.

Comment: You need to review the method signatures. These appear in the autocomplete popup (while writing code in the editor) and have more detail explained on the reference documentation website (use the Help menu).

Comment: I have edited my code to include column = 11 and replaced k with column but still doesn't work. I don't understand why? @TheMaster I have already checked documentation before posting but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: May be you would like to find last row **with data** for a given column ("K" in your case). Correct?

Comment: I would like to write to the last row for a given column @АлександрЕрмолин So there is data filled out in column A I have found the last row with the getLastRow function. I now would like to write a variable (exampleText) to that row. it works if I replace lastRow, column with "K10". But it doesn't work when I try to use variables.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I have posted new code - I get the same error: "Cannot find method getRange(number,number)."

Comment: From what I can see, you're trying to get the range and row from the spreadsheet and not referencing the active sheet. `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` the `.getActiveSheet()` is missing.

Comment: So the problem is located at the last code line. You should use **.setValue()** method for a single string value, not **.setValues()**

Comment: Only [`getRange(string)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) is available on `Spreadsheet`(ss). So, you can use `ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1:B4')`. `getRange(number,number)` is only available on sheet. `ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `getRange` is a method that's available both on `Spreadsheet` class and `Sheet` class.
- However, only [`getRange(string)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) is available on Spreadsheet(ss). So, you can use `ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1:B4')`.
- And [`getRange(number,number)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) is only available on sheet. So, You can use `ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,4)`.
- Sheet class also accepts other variations of this method, but Spreadsheet class doesn't, which only accepts string as the only parameter.
- Sometimes, You also receive

  > Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange

  The reason the first parameter is a string is because there is a attempt by JavaScript engine to match the actual function call signature: `getRange(string)`. It converts the first number to string, but it doesn't know what to do with the rest of the parameters(numbers). As there is no method signature that match the call (string, number,number,number) on `Spreadsheet` class, it throws a error.

#### Solution:

Use proper methods on the intended class as described in the official documentation. For most purposes, You must use the `Sheet` class.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1)
```