# How do I dynamically getRange starting from a specific cell to end of sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm writing a script to copy down all the formulas in my sheet from the third row onwards but I don't want to change anything in my column D. I've been trying to use getRange(#,#,#,#) format but I have this error: "Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number)."

I thought this error meant I was running getRange on the wrong class, but I use getRange in the same function using A1 notation and it works.

Any help debugging this code would be appreciated. I've been working on fixing it for a few days.

```
function Copy_Down() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data_Template'), true);

  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:C').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:C3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

  //it breaks here:
  spreadsheet.getRange(3,5,spreadsheet.getLastRow(),spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).activate(); 
  spreadsheet.getRange(3,5,1,spreadsheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:A1').activate();
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable range to a spreadsheet in google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987422/how-to-declare-a-variable-range-to-a-spreadsheet-in-google-scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in fact calling getRange(number,number,number,number) on the wrong class, as you thought. The "[Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)" class, which you are using, has 3 definitions of the [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) method, but those only accept either A1 notation, or the name of a named range.

The [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) method which accepts numbers is part of the Sheet class, which represents a single sheet within a spreadsheet.

Generally it's a bit simpler to work with a specific Sheet, rather than work via the active sheet.

You'll also need to take into account that getLastRow() and getLastColumn() return numbers which include your starting positions, so you need to subtract those offsets.

This will look something like:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data_Template');
...
sheet.getRange(3,5,sheet.getLastRow()-2,sheet.getLastColumn()-4).activate(); 
sheet.getRange(3,5,1,sheet.getLastColumn()-4).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
```

Comment: The code works, except it misses the last row and column. I changed "-5" to "-4" and "-3" to "-2" which fixes that error. Thank you so much.