# Using Google Sheets macro to populate blank cells in a given column with a default value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I would like to create a function for a Google Spreadsheet that will iterate through the rows in column L and populate blank cells with a default date. I get the following error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

Not sure why `i` is being considered a string.

```
function SetDateWhereBlank() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var defaultDate = new Date(2021,11,31);
  var startRow = 2;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = 12;

  for (var i = startRow; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    // starting at row 2, if the value in column L is blank, populate the cell with the default date
    cell = spreadsheet.getRange(i,column,lastRow-1,1);

    if (cell.isBlank()) { 
      cell.setValue(defaultDate);
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you could use a `setValues()` on a matrix of cells to follow best practices (if you want the script to be fast, ofc) and avoid the problem at all, seems like you use the `getRange` method correctly. Could you please add logging for `typeof i` for each iteration and check again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable range to a spreadsheet in google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987422/how-to-declare-a-variable-range-to-a-spreadsheet-in-google-scripts)

Comment: So that question has fixed the error (replaced `spreadsheet` with `sheet` to accept the `getRange` function with integers as arguments). So now the script runs but it doesn't do anything. As in, the empty cells in column L remain empty. I'm going to try the `setValues()` function to avoid using the `for` loop entirely.

Comment: That should be a new question  with new research.